# is it possible to get complete wordpress blog post in a rss feed?

Tags: rss

I want to include images, time and date stamp?

I'm using the google feed-control Api to load rss feeds but only get the title and body text from it.

I would like to render the entire post blog post using rss feed, also if there is a better way to parse a feed other than the google feed control API

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#feed_control

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to add your complete post to your RSS feed, or import an RSS feed from another website?

Comment: its on the same domain except the im trying to pull in RSS feed into a static HTML page from wordpress site.

Answer (score 4):

To add your complete content to your RSS feed, go to Admin >> Settings >> Reading >> For each article in a feed, show >> Full text